# How do i stop my tcp echo server to work the right way?

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

```
// A simple echo server
// ./server port_no

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>



#define ERROR -1
#define MAX_CLIENTS 2
#define MAX_DATA 1024



main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  struct sockaddr_in client;
  int sock;
  int new;
  int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  int data_len;
  char data[MAX_DATA];


  if((sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == ERROR)
  {
       perror("server socket: ");
       exit(-1);   
  }

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  bzero(&server.sin_zero,8);


  if((bind(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server, sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
  {
          perror("bind : ");
          exit(-1);
  }

  if((listen(sock, MAX_CLIENTS)) == ERROR)
  {
         perror("listen");
         exit(-1);
  }          

  while(1) //Better signal handling required
  {
      if((new == accept(sock, ( struct sockaddr *)&client , &sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
      {
         perror("accept"); 
         exit(-1); 
      }


 printf("New Client connected from port no %d and IP %s\n",ntohs(client.sin_port),inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
 data_len = 1;

 while(data_len)
    {      
       data_len = recv(new,data , MAX_DATA, 0);

             if(data_len)
               {
                    send(new, data, data_len, 0);
                    data[data_len] = '\0' ; // null the last byte to detect string
                    printf("Sent mesg: %s", data);
               }
    }

 printf("Client disconnected\n");

 close(new);
}


close(sock);

}
```

HI i have been learning socket programming in C . And recently i had written a code for tcp echo server. Server does shows connected when i use netstat command but as soon as i run the code using telnet it starts printing infinite messages instead of waiting for me to write a message in other terminal. Please help me figure out where i am i going wrong.

Comment: Please tell us what the actual output is. The message(s) being printed are obviously significant as it will tell where the program is stuck. But for starters, `while(data_len)` and `if (data_len)` are wrong. `recv` returns `-1` on error and in C any non-zero value evaluates to true when used as a conditional. So those checks do not correctly distinguish between success and error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the infinite loop is the code

```
f((new == accept(sock, ( struct sockaddr *)&client , &sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
```

It should instead be

```
f((new = accept(sock, ( struct sockaddr *)&client , &sockaddr_len)) == ERROR)
```

It's == vs =.  With ==, the socket returned by accept() is never assigned to new, so calling recv() on it returns -1 (error in this case), and because the code doesn't check for the error, as pointed out Alan Au, the result is an infinite loop.

BTW, if you watch the compiler warnings or enable more warnings by using a switch, e.g. -Wall with gcc, you can usually get some good insight into possible issues with the code.